# How to get record using group by and sum in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a table like:

```
AttendaceDate                 Attendance
2015-12-05 00:00:00.000       1.00
2015-12-01 00:00:00.000       0.50
2015-11-01 00:00:00.000       1.00
2015-12-01 00:00:00.000       1.00
```

I want the following result:

```
AttendaceDate                 Attendance
November,2015                 2.00
December,2015                 1.50
```

Comment: From the input, the sum on Dec seems to be 2.50 and on Nov 1.00...

Comment: do have any code to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var grouped = (
    from s in context.Table
    group s by new { s.AttendanceDate.Year, s.AttendanceDate.Month } into g
    select new { Year = g.Key.Year, Month = g.Key.Month, Attendance = g.Sum(s => s.Attendance) }
);
```

During display of the data, you can convert the year and month to the text you want to show by doing:

```
new DateTime(g.Year, g.Month, 1).ToString("MMMM,yyyy");
```

Comment: I should note, I purposely separated the formatting logic from the data retrieval logic because IMO that's better. If you need it all in one go for some reason let me know, there are ways to do that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have small table (with small number of records), you can load all rows and then process them like this:

```
var res = dbContext.YouTable.ToList()
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.AttendaceDate.Year, x.AttendaceDate.Month })
    .Select(x => new { x.Key.Year, Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x.Key.Month), Sum = x.Sum(y => y.Attendance)}).ToList();
```